# use regex to modify srt file?

Tags: regex

one format of srt file looks like this:

```
0:00:04 --> 00:00:10
```

and another format looks like this

```
0:00:04,000 --> 00:00:10,000
```

I want to process the first kind of file to append an ,000 to each time-frame for compatibility purposes so that the first file has the ,000 formatting that I need like the above second example.

I was thinking of trying to use some string functions like `mid()`, `right()`, `instring()` but wondered if regex might do the job better, any suggestions on how to do this?

Comment: which language or tool? awk? sed? vim? Java?.....

Comment: Brightscript, which might look like `r = CreateObject("roRegex", "a", "i")
r.ReplaceAll("Abracadabra", "x")`

Answer (score 0):

You can use this regex to match the first group :

```
^([0-9]{1,2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}) --> ([0-9]{1,2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2})$
```

And then replace $1 by $1 + ",000" and $2 by $2 + ",000"

Since you don't indicate which language you used, I did a simple example in PHP :

```
<?php
$string = 'April 15, 2003';
$pattern = '/(\w+) (\d+), (\d+)/i';
$replacement = '${1}1,$3';
echo preg_replace("/^([0-9]{1,2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}) --> ([0-9]{1,2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2})$/i", "$1,000 --> $2,000", "0:00:04 --> 00:00:10");
// output : 0:00:04,000 --> 00:00:10,000
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

With `sed` (it's available on Windows too):

```
sed -i '/\d\+\:\d\+:\d\+ --> \d\+\:\d\+:\d\+/ s_\(\d\+\:\d\+:\d\+\)\s*-->\(\d\+\:\d\+:\d\+\)\s*_\1,000 --> \2,000_' INPUT.srt
```

It will be done inplace.

(*And I know* it's not the correct regex to capture time definitions... but it works for this job.)

Answer (score 0):

Sure, that sounds like a good idea. A simple approach would be to match for `(\d?\d:\d\d:\d\d)` and replace it with the match itself plus `,000` (for "the match itself" use a [back reference](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html), which might be something like `\1` or `$1`, depending on your language).

Try implementing this, and if you need further help, start a new question where you mention what you have tried, where you are stuck and which language you are using.

Answer (score 0):

Why not simply

```
sed -e 's/ -->\|$/,000&/' old.srt >new.srt
```

provided that `old.srt` consistently contains the shorter format only.